# ASP.NET MVC3 and ajax problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, controller

I'm trying to use ajax in my ASP MVC3 application but I have an issue.

Here is my view code :

```
 @Html.Partial("_Topic", Model)

      @Ajax.ActionLink("Afficher les commentaires", "ShowLastArticleComments",
                new AjaxOptions()
                {
                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                    UpdateTargetId = "showComments",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace

                })
    <div id="showComments">

    </div>
}
```

And here is my controller method :

```
 public PartialViewResult ShowLastArticleComments()
        {

          blablabla

            return PartialView("_Comments", comments);
        }
```

When I click on the ajaxed link, it load a full new page instead of just replacing the div by my PartialView called "_Comments". Why?

Thanks,

KiTe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have included the jquery unobtrusive ajax script to your page as that's what AJAXifies the `Ajax.*` helpers (obviously jquery itself should be included as well):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and that unobtrusive javascript is enabled in web.config:

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Comment: yep, the problem came from there.I don't know why, but the unobtrusive-ajax.js wasn't correctly loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Something to try: Use "Post" instead.

Comment: the problem was just that the unobtrusive-ajax?js wasn't loaded correctly, I still don't know why. rewrote my scripts tags, restarted VS and all went better